# Babel Multilingual Hyphenation Order of Precedence?

Tags: babel, languages, hyphenation

When I use multiple languages with Babel (e.g., with `\usepackage[german,french,latin,english]{babel}`), I realize that `english` is the default language because it is the last listed, but what does Babel do when it encounters a non-English word? How does it hyphenate it? Does it look for the word in, in my case, a German, French, or Latin hyphenation dictionary? If so, what if the same word is in multiple dictionaries, although it may be syllabicated differently? How would it hyphenate it then?

Is there an order of precedence is the multilingual documents for hyphenation purposes?

Comment: TeX can't read and doesn't understand languages; it just typesets whatever you pass to it using the rules *you* specify. If you have, say, a German word, use `\foreignlanguage{german}{Götterfunken}`. By the way, `ngerman` should be preferable, as it conforms to the new orthography for German.

Comment: @egrag: Thanks, but I'm typesetting 19th century German. Should `ngerman` still be used for that?

Comment: Oh, no! In that case the old orthography is definitely what you need.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it, Babel will hyphenate every word using the rules for the current (`declared`) language. It doesn't look for the word in any dictionary, in the usual sense, but applies rules  according to *hyphenation patterns* which are specific to each language. These are described in files such as frhyph.tex, dehyphn.tex or dehypht.tex.

Comment: I don't have the files frhyph.tex, dehyphn.tex or dehypht.tex. Where should they be located?

Comment: They're in MiKTeX2.9\tex\generic\hyphen. For TeX Live, they're in texmf-dist\text\generic\hyphen.

Comment: @Geremia If you have a fairly recent TeX distribution, you don't need to worry about the hyphenation files; they are already included in the format you're using.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I have bleeding-edge TeXLive.